# Disqus User Email Not Being Returned

Tags: php, oauth, disqus

With Disqus, I am writing an `OAuth` where I am requesting the user's email, but the email address is not being returned by user's detail.

`OAuth` Response

```
stdClass Object
(
    [username] => Meeeeee
    [user_id] => xxxx638
    [access_token] => xxxxxxxxxx2db3cb0b7c10134e83
    [expires_in] => 2592000
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [state] => 
    [scope] => read,write,email
    [refresh_token] => exxxxxxxx799826a93409f6f98
)
```

User's Detail Request

```
stdClass Object
(
    [username] => Meeeeee
    [numFollowers] => 0
    [about] => 
    [name] => meeeee
    [url] => 
    [joinedAt] => 2014-01-08T15:38:32
    [rep] => 1.231755
    [numFollowing] => 0
    [connections] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [numPosts] => 0
    [reputation] => 1.231755
    [location] => 
    [profileUrl] => http://disqus.com/Meeee/
    [isPrivate] => 
    [numLikesReceived] => 0
    [isPrimary] => 1
    [isAnonymous] => 
    [id] => xxxxxx638
    [avatar] => stdClass Object
        (
            [small] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [permalink] => https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/meeee.jpg
                    [cache] => //a.disquscdn.com/uploads/users/8970/638/avatar32.jpg?1389195513
                )

            [isCustom] => 
            [permalink] => https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/meeee.jpg
            [cache] => //a.disquscdn.com/uploads/users/8970/638/avatar92.jpg?1389195513
            [large] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [permalink] => https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/meeee.jpg
                    [cache] => //a.disquscdn.com/uploads/users/8970/638/avatar92.jpg?1389195513
                )

        )

)
```

As shown in the above the scope does have the user's email. But the API request to user's detail does not contain the email address, which is inconsistent with the [api](http://disqus.com/api/docs/users/details/) . My example was produced in PHP but also has the same response when using their web api.

Comment: Was the original grant made when you had the "email" scope specified? Have you tried this with a new user, or again after revoking your application just to check?

Comment: I'm not sure, its been through many iteration but I surmise no. How would I go about revoking the app permsions entirely and then starting anew?

Comment: Go to http://disqus.com/account/ -- then click the "Applications" tab and revoke your app. Then restart the authorization process. You should see the email permission warning in the new authorization grant window.

Comment: Actually I just tried to an auth from a brand new account, same problem. Email is not present though it shows more information about the user

Comment: Here is a gist of it: https://gist.github.com/ProdigyView/8532148

Comment: Not exactly sure why it doesn't work then - can you email me the exact request with api key/access token? developers@disqus.com

Comment: Did you get my api key and access token? Any idea to what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The `email` scope is only available when using the `audiencesync` grant_type, so this won't work with regular OAuth applications.

Using the standard OAuth flow the only way to obtain an email address is if you:

1. Own a site
2. Use your own authentication (with the `admin` grant_type)
3. The user has participated on your site